# Orion sending error message "connection failed, after 100 retries"

Tags: mongodb, docker, fiware, fiware-orion

I am using Orion and Mongo with Docker, installed as the Fastest Way section of the [documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/user/docker/index.html). All of them are in the same server.

I am able to connect them, and deal with entities and subscriptions (create, update, delete working fine), using volume and persisting my data even after rebooting everything. The annoying part is that Orion continuously send the error message:

> mongoConnectionPool.cpp[194]: Database Error (connection failed, after
>   100 retries: 'couldn't connect to server localhost:27017 (127.0.0.1)
>   failed, connection attempt failed'

Why does Orion give this message if he actually do connect and update information in Mongo? What this message imply and how can I remove it?

```
Notes:
contextBroker --version: 0.26.1
Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd
mongod --version: db version v2.6.11
```

Comment: Could you edit your post to include a dump of your `docker-compose.yml` file, please? I mean, the output of `cat docker-compose.yml`. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you don't link mongodb and orion and orion trying to find mongodb in localhost. Provide your `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Cortwave pointed me out to the solution of this issue.

I do have a link to orion and mongo in my `docker-compose.yml` file. It's a line under the orion's section:

```
orion:
    command: -dbhost mongo
```

But when I stop only the orion container `docker stop orion`, and start it again `docker start orion`, the link is missed.

To fix this, I can stop and start both the containers with `docker-compose stop/start` or, when I stop only orion, I can insert the db information with `docker start orion -dbhost mongo` when start it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, with essentially the same solution, but finding it took me a long time:

be sure not to overwrite 'command: -dbhost mongo' in 'entrypoint:'